# Are Drop-ins harmful for wordpress website?

Tags: plugins

In my wordpress plugins there is a new section, named Drop-ins. I am confused, these drop-ins can harm my website. Actually I am not sure. Can you help me, please. 
Are the Drop-ins are harmful? 
If harmful, how can I solve?

Comment: You will have to explain. What plugin is that? What are the Drop-ins you are talking about? May be a screenshot? Edit your question with those details.

Answer (score 4):

As for every part of your whole Setup, the principle remains the same.

**If every Plugin, Theme, Drop-In, ChildTheme, Core, whatever Code you use is secure if coded properly**

On the other hand, every code on your site can add to the vulnerability of the site.

### Keep everything up to date

This should go without saying, but it is important to your security that you run the latest versions available.

## What is a Drop-In?

From your question I suppose that you are confused as to what a Drop-In actually is.

**Drop-Ins are used to alter Core WordPress files.**

As you know, hacking the Core directly is a bad bad idea. In some cases however, you may want to alter the way WordPress talks to your database, and use your own `db.php`. You can define this class in a file also named `db.php`, and place it in your `WP_CONTENT_DIR` directly (not the Plugin or Theme folder).

If the core WordPress function is available to be altered by a DropIn (not every file has this capability), it will be replaced by your custom file, in our case `db.php`, and is now called a DropIn.

*The advantage is obvious - if you update the core, your changes are not lost.*

**Notice**: If you want to get a list of all the available DropIns (if you use multisite, you get a different result), create a small Plugin which contains the following code. I just dump the result, be sure to handle the output the way it should be.

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: Dropin
 */
function f711_print_dropins() {
    print_r( _get_dropins() );
    return;
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'f711_print_dropins' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this great help. Actually, you are right. I am not clear about the Drop-ins. You did great for me @fischi

Comment: You are very welcome @nahid7 :)

Comment: advanced-cache.php-------------------Advanced caching plugin.                                                 ---------------Should I take any step with this? Actually I am very poor about Wordpress. If I see any other Dropins in the future, should I do anything? or, just will avoid those Drop-ins? I am sorry to bother you. 
Hope, you will reply. @fischi

Comment: As I said, DropIns are not harmful by nature. If for example you have W3TotalCache installed (am I right?), it needs to use another Database Class for database caching. So, nothing to worry about :)